# Why there are so many pending payments for subscription from Google play console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I have an Android application which is using subscription to monetize money. After 7 days of trial, most of active subscriptions are in payment pending status. After 1 day later, it will automatically become cancelled status.

Is this the problem from Google play or the error of my integration ? 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: @abelhoang: When did you integrate in-app subs to your apps? Pending payments appear before or during the pandemic? I just integrated in-app subs in 3/2020. Only a few payments are charged after 7-day trial. I'm contacting with Google Play Support to see if the pandemic is delaying the payments

Comment: Having the same problem. I also couldn't find any documentation. Did you get any support from Google? Any progress about the issue?

Comment: Also having the same problem, did you ever get to the bottom of it? We've been seeing this behaviour since before the pandemic, so that's not the cause for us. Most days for us, out of all charge attempts about 30% are successfully charged and 70% go to Payment pending status. I've contacted Google support on 2 different occasions but haven't been able to get a solid answer. We're still none the wiser if this is just normal or if there is an issue somewhere in our implementation. It would be good to hear from anyone else who's had experience with this...

Comment: I wanted to follow up on this because it is still happening today (almost 2024 now). I opened a ticket with Google some time back and this is what they said:

"It seems that most of the transactions were declined by the user and were declined due to insufficient funds or some bank account related issues. Please be reminded that FundsGuarantee will continue retrying based on various retry configurations."

I'm unsure why they allow so many people to put in bad payment methods. I hope someone else can find a real solution. Maybe its time to move outside the Play Billing library?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that due to quarantine everywhere, including banks, transactions may take longer.
Money just doesn’t reach Google. 
You can enable the console.  Grace period
 Up to 30 days. This will allow you to expect payment within 30 days.

Comment: The year is now 2022 and this issue seems to have only gotten worse. Over 50% of my subscriptions are pending.

Comment: if you not calling enablePendingPurchases() it's help?

Comment: @ShayBen-Hayun If enablePendingPurchases() method is not called, BillingClient instance creation fails. Google doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.Builder#enablePendingPurchases()

Comment: @pedrumgolriz Hey, it's 2023 and still having the same problem, but not 50% in my case is 100%. Could I contact you and talk about? Regards

Comment: @Blast yes sure, I am still having problems as well. Finally, I decided to remove free trials on some of my Android apps as a result. But those that retain the free trial have lots of problems

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing this problem.  If the subscription has a free trial, the payment status remains pending when the free trial period expires but if I remove the free trial then payments are received immediately.

Comment: I'm still facing that problem, but follow the answer of @Денис Бабкевич above. I sometimes got paid from pending payments. (I saw total money earned increased, but could not check which payment change the status because there were too many mixed payment types (pending, chargeable, pending).

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem and have contacted Google about it. They replied saying that the issue is that the money is not reaching them, and that is why it says "Payment Pending". This means that it is an issue with the users payment reaching Google.

From my experience "Payment Pending" happens for around 50% of my subscriptions. For some of them the money arrives around 20 days after the user placed the order and sometimes it never arrives and it goes through to cancelled.

From this it seems that there is nothing we can do to fix this except from increasing Grace Period.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2736362?hl=en#:~:text=If%20the%20auto%2Drenewal%20fails,or%20your%20current%20storage%20plan.

Comment: if you not calling enablePendingPurchases() it's help?

Comment: @ShayBen-Hayun If enablePendingPurchases() method is not called, BillingClient instance creation fails. Google doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.Builder#enablePendingPurchases()